# NSURL directory files

Tags: objective-c, http, directory

I have for example : `www.example.com/` url.

Inside that URL there are few directories for example `www.example.com/dir1/` and inside that there are images when clicked I get `www.example.com/dir1/image1.jpg`.

My problem is that I need to get all files inside `www.example.com/dir1/` , so all images that are inside that directory on web. Based on that names I can get final url (like `www.example.com/dir1/image1.jpg`) but I need to get all the names of images and dunno how.

Thanks.

Comment: first off, your .htaccess needs to allow listing of files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing the apache directory listing you can parse that html and get all your .jpg files.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios is a tutorial on how to parse HTML

Answer (score 0):

If this is on your server, you need some mechanism to retrieve the names of the files.

For example, if PHP, this is a script that returns a JSON response of all of the JPG/PNG files:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

$files = scandir('.');
$images = array();

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,'.'),1)))
    {
       case 'png':
       case 'jpeg':
       case 'jpg': $images[] = $file;
    }
}

echo json_encode($images);

?>
```

You can then use `NSURLConnection` (or AFNetworking or whatever) to retrieve this and convert the JSON to a `NSArray`.

For example, using AFNetworking:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourwebserver.com/some/path/images.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        [self doSomethingWithImageNames:responseObject];
    else
        NSLog(@"expected array, received: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"AFHTTPRequestOperation error: %@", error);
}];
[op start];
```

Or `NSURLConnection`:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", connectionError);
        return;
    }

    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSArray *imageNames = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

    if (jsonError) {
        NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData error: %@", jsonError);
        return;
    }

    [self doSomethingWithImageNames:imageNames];
}];
```

---

If you have to rely upon the HTML response, while you generally shouldn't use regular expressions, in this limited use case, you can probably get away with it. In my case, my web server reports links to the files using `<a href="...">filename</a>` syntax, so I can grab those `href` tags with something like:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if (![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Was expecting `NSData` and got %@", responseObject);
        return;
    }

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a\\s[\\s\\S]*?href\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:string
                            options:0
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                         usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                             [results addObject:[string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]]];
                         }];

    [self doSomethingWithImageNames:results];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"AFHTTPRequestOperation error: %@", error);
}];
[op start];
```

Comment: Like I wrote in upper comment, I used AFHTTPRequestOperation and got whole html back from nsurlrequest. What could be the error, or its not error, just have to handle that html response now and substring images ?

Comment: @ŽeljaHuber What I'm suggesting is that you do *not* rely on the web server's returning a directory contents in HTML, but rather write a script for your server to return the list of filenames in a JSON format, which is easily parsed by AFNetworking.

Comment: I agree, but its not mine webserver and client doesn't want to change anything server side so... Thanks anyway on suggestion.

Comment: @ŽeljaHuber Understood. While you should use the HTML parser of the accepted answer, in this limited example, you could probably also get away with regular expression, as shown at the end of my modified answer.

Comment: Worked out with TFHpple category from above answer but thanks anyway.